# Closing the cursor of a ResultSet?

Tags: java, jdbc, io, transactions

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) oracle java tutorial:

> The following statement specifies that the cursor of the ResultSet
>   object generated from the getPrice query is closed when the commit
>   method is called. Note that if your DBMs does not support
>   ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT, then this constant is ignored:

```
getPrice = con.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);
```

Does it mean that `ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` closes the `ResultSet`?
It appears from the name that it just closes the cursore of the ResultSet.. what use would it be if that was the case?
PS: I am aware that the closing of whatever the thing happens after `con.commit()`. But what actually get closed? the cursor? what do they mean by the cursor? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT) says:

> The constant indicating that open ResultSet objects with this holdability will be closed when the current transaction is commited.

So yes, the result set itself will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is closed only after call of commit method.

Comment: I understand that, but why closing only  the cursor? what's the scope of it? Does it perhaps mean closing the whole result set?

Comment: Hi, in this case, if you call commit the whole resultset will be closed (after you call commit() method) and you cannot read from it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**About cursor:**
[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases)) an explanation of what is cursor; Wiki explain what is cursor related to a resultset from database view.

From a JDBC programmer view:

> You access the data in a ResultSet object through a cursor. Note that
> this cursor is not a database cursor. This cursor is a pointer that
> points to one row of data in the ResultSet. Initially, the cursor is
> positioned before the first row. The method ResultSet.next moves the
> cursor to the next row. This method returns false if the cursor is
> positioned after the last row. This method repeatedly calls the
> ResultSet.next method with a while loop to iterate through all the
> data in the ResultSet.

---

**About Statement.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT**

> `Statement.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT`: The constant indicating that open
> ResultSet objects with this holdability will be closed when the
> current transaction is commited.
>
> Closing cursors when this
> method is called can result in better performance for some
> applications.

So yes, cursor will be (theoretically) closed; I wrote theoretically because

> if your DBMs does not support ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT, then
> this constant is ignored